# Simplest way to target GameObjects properties when it triggers/collides?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

If I have a trigger or collision I want to target that gameObject and have access to it's properties for each of the attached scripts. I managed to do it like this but I know there has to be a better method right?

Here I wanted to target the script attached to the triggered game object labeled "BoxManager" and then BoxManager's property "isHeld" If the target is being selected dynamically like this when it interacts with the trigger/collision I have to use the target object, but is there a better way to do the rest?

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D target)
{
    if (target.gameObject.tag == "Box")
    {
        if (target.attachedRigidbody.GetComponent<BoxManager>().isHeld == false)
        {
            target.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * thrust);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To do the rest of what? Getting the component to access a member is the normal way to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `target.attachedRigidbody.GetComponent<BoxManager>()` is totally unnecessary and redundant. I've seen people even do worse with code such as  `target.attachedRigidbody.gameObject.transform.GetComponent<BoxManager>();`. That's doing the-same thing because they are all attached to one GameObject.

You can and should simply that to `target.GetComponent<BoxManager>();`.

---

As for using `GetComponent` function all the time to get another script during collision, that's fine. It is the easiest way to get another Script that is attached to the GameObject during collision before you can access the variables in side that script.

Although, I find it annoying that you must do `GetComponent` in the `OnTriggerStay2D` just for that. It get's more annoying when you have so many scripts to check.

This is your collision function:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D target){}
```

And you need to access your `BoxManager` script from target after collision....

A tricky way would be to use a `Dictionary`. In the `Start` function initialize the Dictionary and use `Collider2D` as the key and `BoxManager` as the value.

Update this Dictionary when you instantiate and destroy GameObjects with `Collider2D` and `BoxManager` during game-play.

Something like this:

```
Dictionary<Collider2D, BoxManager> scriptID = new Dictionary<Collider2D, BoxManager>();
```

Then inside your collision function, use `TryGetValue` and the `target` variable  as the key to get the `BoxManager` component.

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D target)
{
    if (target.CompareTag("Box"))
    {
        BoxManager result;
        scriptID.TryGetValue(target, out result);

        if (!result.isHeld)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

In fact, if you **%100 sure** that this object has the `BoxManager` script attached to it, you can do that in one line of code with without the `TryGetValue` function:

```
void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D target)
{
    if (target.CompareTag("Box"))
    {
        BoxManager result = scriptID[target];
    }
}
```

You can reduce the chances of detecting Object without the `BoxManager` script by using `target.CompareTag` like above. Notice how I changed your `target.gameObject.tag` to `target.CompareTag`. It recommended to use `target.CompareTag`.

**Now the code has been simplified with** `BoxManager result = scriptID[target];` while using `target.CompareTag("Box")` as a guard so that you don't have to use `TryGetValue` or the `ContainsKey` function.

Below is what the example of the whole script should look like:

```
Dictionary<Collider2D, BoxManager> scriptID = new Dictionary<Collider2D, BoxManager>();
public BoxManager boxManagerPrefab;

void Start()
{
    //Register your BoxManager instances to the Dictionary
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        BoxManager bc = Instantiate(boxManagerPrefab) as BoxManager;
        //Use Isntance ID of the Script as id
        Collider2D cld2D = boxManagerPrefab.GetComponent<Collider2D>();
        scriptID.Add(cld2D, bc);
    }
}

void OnTriggerStay2D(Collider2D target)
{
    if (target.CompareTag("Box"))
    {
        BoxManager result = scriptID[target];

        if (!result.isHeld)
        {
            target.attachedRigidbody.AddForce(transform.right * thrust);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the detailed answer. Still trying to wrap my head around some OOP concepts and knew there had to be a more logical way to target what I wanted. Thanks for the advice. Any good unity resources besides the official documentation you'd recommend?

Comment: Unity uses CBSE not OOP but you can use both. Most things are done by attaching scripts to a GameObject.  See [here](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) for Official Unity C# tutorial. If you really want to learn Unity I suggest you follow one or more of their [project tutorials](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials). You will 
 learn a lot by doing that.