# GetComponent to calculate damage

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm making a endless shooter game, where the bullet is just a object that goes forward until it hits something.

*The enemies all have a script with an HP.*

I want to know if it's to expensive to do:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) {
    if(TagsAndHashes.IsTagEnemy(collision.transform.tag))
        DamageHandler.CauseDamage(collision.gameObject.GetComponent<EnemyBehavior>());
}else{
    pool.ReturnObject(gameObject);
}
```

This way I would be calling `GetComponent<EnemyBehavior>()` every time a player shoots an enemy.

Is it too costly or is it fine?

*The game is for mobile.*

Thanks.

Comment: You tell us. We can't use profiler for your game. Check and see how expensive it is yourself.

Comment: It's fine when `GetComponent` is used in the Collision callback  functions but not good when used in the `Update` function. If you still don't want to use it then you can actually use `Dictionary` to do that. I described this same issue in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43934277/simplest-way-to-target-gameobjects-properties-when-it-triggers-collides/43935848#43935848)  post.

Comment: Callling GetComponent<>() isn't *that* expensive. You just want to avoid doing it all the time (e.g. in an Update method). So you're "probably fine" although as noted there are more efficient ways.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be more logical and less costly to flip who is responsible for damage here.

1. Have a script on the enemy that detects collisions.
2. Have that method check the tag of the object which is colliding with it.
3. Then use the script already on the enemy gameobject to issue damage to itself.

This way the script does not have to go and get a reference for the other object which is of course expensive. Instead it just talks to itself... like I do.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Great idea! Thank you